# Is this an answer or a comment?

Tags: discussion, answers

Someone has posted a "Why is my code crashing", to which someone answered with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30021290/3073006):

> Have you heard of [Exception Handling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173162.aspx)? Read about it and do exception handling in your code. So that you can see what is the error.
>
> However, you can still [debug](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx) your code to see where it is crashing. Start the program by pressing F5 and move line by line to see where it is crashing.

I'm not quite sure if that consists an answer - as it doesn't *answer* the question, or if it should be a comment?

Comment: If you on review task just skip it.Some time I am also confuse with such type answer.I think it should be comment. I saw many  comment type answer has many up-vote and also accepted.

Comment: I would guess that it should be a comment because you are right, it doesn't really answer the question as much as it nudges the asker in the right direction.

Comment: It's probably something that would have been better posted as a comment. It's not quite 'not an answer', but as an answer it's pretty poor. I'd down-vote it.

Comment: I would flag that as Not An Answer (it's not) and vote to close the question.

Comment: Personally if I asked a vague debugging question, I'd much rather receive generally applicable advice on troubleshooting techniques (like this non-answer), than simply a solution to the problem. "Teach a man to fish" and all that.

Comment: @TopherHunt: Personally, if I asked a vague debugging question, I'd much rather have the question closed, with some hints (in comments) on how to ask a better question, because then I'd learn how to use this site (which, in 2015, is almost as important a skill as knowing how to debug). Of course it would be even _better_ if I got some hints (in comments) on how to debug things.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think that when someone asks an incredibly open ended question like *"Why is my code crashing?"*, it's equally fine to answer with an open ended answer giving instructions on how to debug. But that doesn't really help anyone, we end up with a low value answer on a low value question.

For review purposes, this is an answer but not a good quality one (you do have to watch out for low rep users posting answers that should be comments but they have insufficient rep to be able to comment - this is not one of those). The appropriate thing to do is to down vote it. The question is not particularly good either - there is next to no details of the exception, and there is a fair chance that the supplied code has nothing to do with it (and the supplied code cannot be run in isolation).

Unless the problem is obvious from the posted code, this question should be closed as *Off topic*:

[image]

until the OP can isolate the problem a little more and post a more detailed and exact question.

Comment: I agree with most of what you said, but feel that you should at least point them in the right direction first.  SO feels a little hostile at times with its hidden rules and aggressive moderators.  Instructing them on how to get the information needed so they can write a proper question will smooth the process of learning the rules.

Comment: @Trisped I would say that the moderation is *efficient* rather than *aggressive*. When any of those close reasons are used a banner is inserted under the question with an explanation of the closure, and it also contains a bunch of relevant links. Of course we can't make a user click on those links to learn more, but if you think improvements can be made to those banners then you can make a suggestion here on Meta.

Comment: @Trisped: I agree that it's _nice_ to add comments along with a close vote. I often tell people "That question is way too vague to answer, but here's a hint: ___" or "That's a great question, but not appropriate for SO because ___, but here's a hint: ___". But often I don't. And I certainly don't demand that everyone else do so. The close vote is the right thing to do; the comments are an extra when you're feeling helpful.